# Need, recommendations on choosing a good database driver

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm almost done with the html/css side of my site and want to add database that will allow users to save profiles and search it using PHP search engine. However I've never worked with MYSql before and was wondering which method I should use. I checked my hosting CP and there are three possible options: managing MSSQL, managing MYSQL and managing MySQL through PHP
Which one do you suggest is the easiest and best to use?

Comment: Mysql is fast and easy, so just install it.  or install XMPP to get all at the same time,i.e. webserver(apache)/php/mysql

Comment: Choose mysql. I'm not sure what the difference would be between solution 2 and 3 though...

Comment: @phpNoOb: MySQL is fast because it doesn't conform to what you'd expect from an RDBMS. For example, CHECK constraints or the GROUP BY extensions. But, it's easy to start with

Comment: Is it `managing MySQL through PHP` or `managing MySQL through PHPMyAdmin` ? MySQL and PHPMyAdmin are standard tools.

Comment: it says through PHP but once I clicked one it I had the option to Install phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very subjective question, and doesn't really have a *correct* answer.

I'd tend to go with MySQL due to the large amount of info available online. It's been one of the most popular database systems for a long time and has an enormous community to fall back on when you run into problems.

The "managing MySQL through PHP" option sounds like they just provide phpMyAdmin (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) which isn't a bad thing as it will give you a nice web-gui for fiddling with the DB. If you're used to graphical tools this is probably the way to go.

MSSQL, although a good product and quite performant, doesn't seem to have the community support that MySQL has, but it does have good commercial support if you can afford it.

Comment: I've never worked on MySQL before so would you please tell me how to start, should I first download MySQL tool from its official site or how does it work?

Comment: xampp for windows is great as a standard apache + mysql + php + perl development environment. If you only work on the server, use the CP provided or phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is it possible to work on my pc and upload later to the server? My CP is available for one of my domain names but the database I'm creating is for another domain name with free parking(not yet online). Also is it possible to work through phpmyadmin on this server and then upload the result to another server?

Comment: Yes, to all questions but you need to research the best practices. It's usually not a good idea to develop on the live server so as @Adder suggested, xampp (sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/‎) is probably a good place to start. The database can be moved / copied by dumping it to a SQL file using phpMyAdmin and then importing on the other server.

Comment: @Intermernet to create database using xampp I should master PHP Right? I'm not really that good in PHP but I can learn it if its nessassary

Comment: @mkiller1001 you can create the database graphically in phpMyAdmin but to do anything powerful with it you'll need to learn a language to access it. PHP does this nicely, but you can also use pretty much any language that can talk to MySQL.